# Bind Object Properties to Chart in C#

Tags: c#, object, data-binding, charts

I have a list of objects:

```
List<NFutures> futureContracts = new List<NFutures>();
```

What I would like to do is the following:
Every time I change the value of a object property in the list:

```
foreach (NFuture fut in futureContracts)
{
    if (fut.Name == aName)
    { 
         fut.PriceLast = i.StatusLine.Last;
    }
}
```

The chart will update.
The class definition is...

```
public class NFuture : NInstrument
{
    public double Dtm { get; set; }
    public double PriceLast { get; set; }
```

etc ...
How can this be done in an easy way?

Comment: What sort of chart? More explanation would be useful

Answer (score 1):

futureContracts.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name ==aName).PriceLast = "your Value";

Comment: actually I would like to know how to bind the chart to the futureContracts List